# Change the inner margins according to the page count

Tags: geometry

One of the Amazon -- KDP requirements for print books is that the inner margins be determined by the page count of the book, so that larger books have more gutter -- more specifically, according to the formula:

| Page Count | Inside (Gutter) Margins |
| --- | --- |
| 24 to 150 pages | 0.375” (9.6 mm) |
| 151 to 300 pages | 0.5” (12.7 mm) |
| 301 to 500 pages | 0.625” (15.9 mm) |
| 501 to 700 pages | 0.75” (19.1 mm) |
| 701 to 828 pages | 0.875” (22.3 mm) |

as seen [here](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G202145400).

How can one start out with the `geometry` package and set the inside margins according to the page count?

Comment: Their wording is a bit odd—they specify "at least" on the outside margins but not the inside margin, but I would argue that it applies to inside margins as well and those would be minimum margins and not an absolute standard margin.

Comment: If you're automating the setting, it will take a minimum of two passes—the second to reset the margins after getting a page count—but that will likely cause other page-dependent settings to change (e.g., page references, table of contents and indexing). Far better to just set it to a value based on the estimate of the page count and adjust it if after writing/editing the estimate is wrong.

Comment: @DonHosek, on thousands of books that may be a bit hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup provides you with a dynamic way of setting the `inner` dimension based on the number of pages within your document. It uses the latest (Oct 2020) LaTeX kernel that defines `\@abspage@last` to capture the total number of pages within your document within the `.aux`. As an alternative one can also use the [`lastpage` package](//ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) to achieve the same goal. Since it uses the `.aux` for page totals, it does require at least two compilations for things to settle (if you run over the page boundary breakpoints).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \providecommand{\@abspage@last}{1}% Ensure \@abspage@last is defined
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\newgeometry{
      inner=\ifnum\@abspage@last<151
        0.375in
      \else\ifnum\@abspage@last<301
        0.5in
      \else\ifnum\@abspage@last<501
        0.625in
      \else\ifnum\@abspage@last<701
        0.75in
      \else
        0.875in
      \fi\fi\fi\fi
    }}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 40 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 79 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 119 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 162 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 202 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 242 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 283 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 328 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 369 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 410 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 451 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 492 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 538 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 579 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 621 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 662 pages
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]% 719 pages

\end{document}
```

In principle the you set the `inner` geometry using `\newgeometry` at the beginning of the document.

Comment: The `last pages package uses the last page number which is not necessarily the total number of pages.

Comment: @DonHosek: Sure. There is also the `zref-abspage` module from [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref).